# Fail in installing DBD::mysql in Mac using cpanm

Tags: mysql, installation, config, cpanm

I am constantly failing in installing DBD::mysql.
The command I used was:

```
brew install mysql
cpanm DBD::mysql
```

The error I got was:

```
--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DV/DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring DBD-mysql-4.050 ... N/A
! Configure failed for DBD-mysql-4.050. See /Users/jeji/.cpanm/work/1642350924.83890/build.log for details.
```

Therefore, I checked by log file. My log file read:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.9018 on perl 5.030003 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
Work directory is /Users/jeji/.cpanm/work/1642350924.83890
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP: 6.44
You have LWP::Protocol::https: 6.07
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 3.5.1 - libarchive 3.5.1 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.8 
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching DBD::mysql () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DV/DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz
Entering DBD-mysql-4.050
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have DBI 1.609 ... Yes (1.643)
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.174)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have Devel::CheckLib 1.09 ... Yes (1.14)
Configuring DBD-mysql-4.050
Running Makefile.PL


PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the
database user 'jeji' can connect to your MySQL server
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others.

mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'jeji'@'localhost' identified by 's3kr1t';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config) = -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.27_1/include/mysql
  embedded      (guessed     ) = 
  ldflags       (guessed     ) = 
  libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.27_1/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -lzstd -lssl -lcrypto -lresolv
  mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default     ) = 0
  nossl         (default     ) = 0
  testdb        (default     ) = test
  testhost      (default     ) = 
  testpassword  (default     ) = 
  testport      (default     ) = 
  testsocket    (default     ) = 
  testuser      (guessed     ) = jeji

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc DBD::mysql::INSTALL'.

Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Can't link/include C library 'ssl', 'crypto', aborting.
-> N/A
Checking dependencies from META.json ...
Checking if you have Time::HiRes 0 ... Yes (1.9760)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have Test::Deep 0 ... Yes (1.130)
Checking if you have Test::Simple 0.90 ... Yes (1.302162)
Checking if you have bigint 0 ... Yes (0.51)
Checking if you have DBI 1.609 ... Yes (1.643)
-> FAIL Configure failed for DBD-mysql-4.050. See /Users/jeji/.cpanm/work/1642350924.83890/build.log for details.
```

I do think that 'Can't link/include C library 'ssl', 'crypto', aborting.
-> N/A' is the part that is causing the issue, but I have no clue in how to approach the problem.
Any solutions would be great!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got DBD::mysql installed on macOS:

```
cpan -T DBI

sudo cpanm DBD::mysql -n \
 --configure-args="--libs='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lperconaserverclient'"
```

I was installing [Percona Server](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server) instead of MySQL so you might not need the last option.

---

Update: In more recent releases of MacOS, I can't get this to work. I tried for a few days to resolve the compile errors, but then I gave up. I'll use Python now. The era of Perl is over, which makes me sad because I've enjoyed using Perl since around 1996.

Comment: Failed with perl-5.12.1 brew install: "Unknown option: libs". --configure-args="LIBS=..etc.." worked,

Comment: @user1255933, I've given up using Perl on MacOS. I haven't been able to compile DBD::mysql for the past couple of releases of MacOS. It's sad, but the days of Perl on MacOS are over for me. I'll code in Python now.

Comment: @BillKarwin : agreed. Perl is a pain on MacOS esp. on Silicon chips. It's a good idea to switch to Python if you have the choice.